# "what should be done when foul play by an employee damaging company is discovered?

Tags: unprofessional-behavior

Let's say I have this random friend, let`s call him Mark. 
Mark is an employee at this not so interesting company that, for once, has a great opportunity lined up in the form of a partnership with a much larger corporation (aka *other party*, *prospective partner*).

Mark takes a big role in the talks between the two companies as Mark is the only one speaking well the other party`s language, everything is progressing good.

All of a sudden the other party's representatives start ignoring Mark's phone calls, emails, Skype calls.

Knowing very well the culture of the prospective partner company Mark is positive he did not do nor say absolutely anything offensive or whatsoever so he starts asking opinions/informations from colleagues to better understand the sudden tie-cut.

What comes up from various source is that at a recent trade show one of Mark`s company salesman/materials buying manager ("Bob") was approached by a manager of the prospective partner and guess what.... **Bob started basically insulting the prospective party representative in broken English!**

You can guess the reaction of the representative and how of a NO-NO Mark`s company has become for the other company. Months of works vanished.

Now that Bob single-handedly destroyed what could have been a great international partnership is proposing a way smaller and comparatively insignificant company as a partner.

Guess what, this crappy company is owned by Bob's friend and he has (undeclared) stakes in it.

The suspicion that he sabotaged a potentially great partnership in order to get personal gains is too high to ignore for Mark.

What should Marrk do? STFU and get a new job asap or activities potentially damaging the company business should be escalated to management? Has he done enough?

**UPDATE**
Mark went to HR, asked him to lunch and has been  blunt.
HR was baffled to say the least, called senior salesman and the response was "I learnt about it around 1h ago, was going to call you, I may resign". HR was baffled to the Nth power. 
He said he himself wonders if owner is aware of such behaviour and told Mark that whilst he has a great exteem of Mark and would like to have him in the team for long he wouldn't blame him if is to accept a job somewhere else and he is pondering that too. Probably there is something deeply rotten in Mark's company and he should look for a more sane environment.

Since this has been deemed off-topic I rephrase it at "what should be done when foul play by an employee damaging company is discovered", I hope this is not off topic anymore.

Comment: What is "Mark's" role in the company?

Comment: Have you reported Bob's behaviour to management (or are they aware?)? If you're looking for help with how to do that, that might make for a more appropriate question.

Comment: @PhilipKendall  Mark is an Engineer and has also a salesman role in English speaking countries

Comment: @Dukeling I am not Mark. Mark has talked about this to the HR guy and the HR is very well aware of this and other shady activities from Bob. HR himself questions why the owner still employs Bob. Mark is not much worried about "justice", he is worried at not losing his time and opportunities to due other people misconduct.

Comment: Not HR, but management. This seems like an issue that's outside of the scope of what HR (generally) does. Or are you implying the owner is aware of Bob's behaviour?

Comment: @Dukeling Mark went to HR, update soon in post.

Comment: Traditionally an anonymous note from "a friend"  sent to either a board member or if large enough a company's internal security division is one route.

Comment: There isn't really a "should" here. Depending on the specifics, it may be appropriate to discuss this with the owner directly. It's always appropriate to leave the company (within the terms of one's contract). But it mostly comes down to what one wants to do.

Answer (score 2):

The notion that "Bob" was trying to deliberately sabotage the negotiations in order to get the business for his friend's company is, on the face of it, quite a likely one. It is however relatively hard to *prove* and therefore take action against Bob on directly. However the fact that his behavior in insulting the potential partner's representative was damaging to the company's interests is much clearer and something that is definitely due some form of disciplinary action (his intentions or lack thereof are irrelevant there) - it's not acceptable or professional behavior and there will likely be terms in Bob's employment contract that expressly prohibit doing that sort of thing, especially given that Bob was acting as a representative of the company given that it was a trade show.

So what Mark needs to do is get a meeting set up with Bob (if Mark isn't Bob's manager it would be best to get them to do this instead) in order to investigate the allegations that Bob was behaving unprofessionally and contrary to the company's interests at this trade show. Mark's company likely has it's own disciplinary procedures so the exact process will vary but I imagine it will essentially consist of whomever is running this meeting presenting Bob with the fact there have been multiple reports of what he said/did and asking him to explain himself (which I doubt he'll be able to do satisfactorily) and from there disciplinary action can be taken according to the procedures the company has in place, assuming this doesn't result in firing (in some companies/jurisdictions you can't go from 0-Fired without some extremely egregious circumstances) it would have to be accompanied by a rather firm warning that such behavior is unacceptable and that any future recurrences will be viewed very poorly.

Comment: Bob is WAY more senior than Marl, Mark is a recent hire (2 years vs 15) who was called in specifically for his past success of reacing out a way bigger corporation and successfully closing a deal whilst at his previous employer so a face to face confrontation is not an option

Comment: @Caterpillaraoz Ouch :( Added to your recent update in the main post I think in this instance Mark should probably run for the hills. I'll leave my answer as-is for now since I think it's appropriate for the more general question at least.

Comment: Mark is pleased to announce he left the company!!!

Comment: @Caterpillaraoz sounds like a result!